# Detecting Touch from TOP/BOTTOM

Tags: objective-c, ios, touch

I'm a beginer on IOS Development, I've developed a simple demo of detecting multiple touch by following this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Detecting_iOS_4_iPhone_Touch_Screen_Gesture_Motions):

It works fine, but my question is: when I try to start the touch from the outside of the iphone ( from TOP or BOTTOM), the touch is not detected, and when i tried to do the same thing from LEFT/Right sides, it works. Can someone explain to me, why the touch is not detected when I try dragging from the top or the bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by 'outside of the iphone'? You starts dragging on phone surface and moves finger to phone screen?

Comment: It would be nice to get some feedback from you at least now that bounty is over and there are less than 24 hours left to award it before half of it goes to waste :)

Comment: @fichek , sorry man , i've some problem with my connection that's why i coudn't log on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't start from top because the status bar picks up the touch. You know how when you tap status bar, scrolled content goes to top? That's why status bar "steals" your touch. If you remove status bar (you can do that in app's Info.plist) you will get touches from top, even with iOS 5 and it's "pull from top" notification center. (A small pulldown handle will appear on first pulldown, and if you pull again, notification center will steal your touches.)

It should however start from bottom unless there is some kind of tab bar or other toolbar that also picks up touches.

Comment: that's logic , but i'm developing an app in Landscape mode, and the status bar is hidding from the file plist . but the touch can't be start from thr TOP , :(

Comment: Keep in mind with iOS 5 coming they are using a swipe down gesture from the top to open the new Notification Center, you will need to design your app around this core feature of the OS.

Comment: i know that, but i'm not developing now on IOS5 , and the second thing is that in my application , i've hidded the status Bar , so my app is running on Full Screen on Landscape Mode .

Answer (score 5):

The status bar will get the touch event instead of your view.
You may hide the status bar by:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

Or just set the **Status bar is initially hidden** property in the info.plist file.

In addition, if your running iOS 5, the behavior will be different when the status bar is hidden: you can get the event from your view but the system will also drop down a little floating drag bar.

If you don't want to hide the status bar, you may try to set the windows layer and put the view above the status bar(not sure whether this is allowed in the AppStore or not).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's desactivated because of the future release of iOS 5, who allows you to display notification center by touching from the top to the bottom of your iphone.

As I'm running on iOS 5 I can't give you more details cause I cannnot test, but I think it's the most likely answer

Comment: i've the same problem when i've try to run it on landscape mode , the top /bottom drag doesnt work ; i cant understand why it isn't possible to run from at least from the bottom. anyway ,thanks for your answer, i appreciate that.:)

Answer (score 1):

Using this code in `loadView` of a `UIViewController`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

UIView* mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.size.width, screen.size.height)];
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.view = mainView;

mainView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

[mainView release];
```

All touches are picked up when sliding from off the screen into it in any direction and orientation. Notice that the size of the view always occupies the entire screen.

I believe the others are correct in saying that the status bar will get the touch events if it is visible. Also, if the view doesn't span the entire screen it may not get events. For example, if the frame's y-coordinate is 20, it will not pick up the touch when sliding your finger from the top.

Answer (score 0):

The previous responses around the status bar are totally right I think.

Remember also that underneath the gesture recogniser stuff is some more powerful but more complicated to program touch APIs.

The basic element is a UIEvent which has touchBegan, touchEnded, touchCancelled and touchMoved methods. Check the docs on this as I'm somewhat going from memory here... Anyway you can see that if an even needs to open with touchBegan, then starting the gesture outside the touch-sensitive area might not fly. 
Left to right stuff probably works mostly because the area between screen and edge is slim enough that touch will be picked up even if you're not right on the screen. Top to bottom and bottom to top however have wider areas where you'll likely start outside of an area of response.

Comment: "Top to bottom and bottom to top however have wider areas where you'll likely start outside of an area of response." - this makes no sense at all. It doesn't matter if you slide your finger onto capacitive sensor or touch it, it will recognize your finger the same way. Feel free to try with Safari. Open a webpage and scroll down, then touch the top of the device and slide down until you hit the status bar. You will see it will scroll to top.

Comment: you're right because it registers it as a touch in the status bar. However if you continue downwards the device won't recognise it as a swipe because it has no entry in touchesBegan. If you have an example from code not just a single instance of device behaviour please share.

Comment: Of course you will not get touchesBegan because status bar got that, and will get all the touchesMoved that follow, as well as touchesEnded or touchesCanceled.